# jQuery variables for selectors

Tags: jquery, variables

Im having issues setting a variable for something before its clicked. I want to put the var fvs in the selector, but it is set afterwards. So, ...

How do I change

```
$(function(){

        $(".fvspan").on("click", ".favebtn", function(){
        var fvs = $(this).attr('id');
            if(fvs)
            {...}
            else { }                    
        }); 
    });
```

To this

```
$(function(){       
var id = fvs    
        $("#" + id + ".fvspan").on("click", ".favebtn", function(){
        var fvs = $(this).attr('id');
            if(fvs)
            {...}
            else { }                    
        }); 
    });
```

How would I declare var id? I know this line is wrong, just an example.

```
var id = fvs
```

Comment: `var id = $('.fvspan').attr('id')` ? But this will give you the id of the first element with `fvspan` class. Is that what you want?

Comment: Can you add the click event to every $(".fvspan") instead and than retreive the id of the clicked element?

Comment: Krishna: that doesnt wbecause I have more than one element that I need to retrieve id's. Simon: That's what I'm doing but the event occurs as many times as there are elements.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! i ran the js script in the loop. I took it out and it works!